# How many times does a (for) loop iterate?

Tags: for-loop

Basic question:

```
for(int i=start;i<=end;i+=step){
    System.out.println("Test");
}
```

start < end

How often is run through the loop, respectively what is the mathematical formula ?

Comment: Trick question? Is `start < end` ? Do you mess with `i` in the body?

Comment: start < end and nothing is done inside the loop.

Comment: None. It is optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx
with nothing on the inside, it will not run at all.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. It does something inside the loop, but the variable "i" doesn't change inside the loop. And it's a serious question. And I'm dumb -.-

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a homework problem and shows a lack of effort.

Comment: It's not a homework problem, I just don't get it. I let the user initialize the variables and create an array. The array's size has to be the number of iterations. I could just create an ArrayList and then copy the items to an array, but I think the mathematical formula is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is shorthand for the following code:

```
int i = start;
if (i <= end) {
    /* loop body */
    i += step;
}
```

To answer your question, it will run `ceiling((end - start + 1) / step)` times. Walk through the logic on paper to see if you come to the same conclusion.

Comment: start=0, end=10, step=3. Iterates 4 times, but (10-0)/3=3.33

Comment: @user Apply the `ceiling` function to the result.

Answer (score 2):

We need to know what the values of start, end, and step are.

```
if:
  start = 0;
  end = 10;
  step = 1;
```

It would loop 11 times, each time adding 1 to the previous value of i until it is <= 10. (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)

```
if:
  start = 0;
  end = 10;
  step = 2;
```

It would loop 6 times, each time adding 2 to the previous value of i until it is <= 10. (0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)

```
if:
  start = 10;
  end = 100;
  step = 10;
```

It would loop 10 times, each time adding 10 to the previous value of i until it is <= 100. (10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100)

And so on.

Comment: That's the point. I need to know the (mathematical) answer with the variables, not with values.

Comment: Alternatively, we can give a mathematical function in terms of `start`, `end`, and `step`.